# Tuple<ThisThing, bool> parameter for OnNavigatedToAsync in Template 10

Tags: c#, uwp, tuples, template10, c#-7.0

Should I be able to pass a `Tuple` as a parameter to `OnNavigatedToAsync`? Is there a better way to pass this kind of information?

I've tried this, but I keep getting an invalid cast exception in the `Value =` line below. Value is typed as `Tuple<ThisThing, bool>`

ViewModel.cs:

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
        Value = (Tuple<ThisThing, bool>)((suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value))) ? suspensionState[nameof(Value)] : parameter);
}
```

Passing parameter as a `Tuple`.

```
public void GoToDetailsPage() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(ThisThingPage), (new ThisThing() { Prop1=1, Prop2=2}, true));
```

**Edit1:**
I've already tried simplifying this to

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
    Value = (Tuple<ThisThing, bool>)parameter;
}
```

and when debugging and stepping into `OnNavigatedToAsync`, and hovering over `parameter` I can see that it is what I expect, a `Tuple`, but results in an `InvalidCastException` on the next line.

Comment: don't put everything in one line when you are debugging. you can have `var x = suspensionState[nameof(Value)]` therefor with debugger you can check what `x` actually is. apparently its not a `Tuple<ThisThing, bool>`

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned I already did something similar. Editing original post.

Comment: It appears `ValueTuple` is not a `Tuple`. Digging into that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that C# 7.0 tuples are not `System.Tuple`, they're `System.ValueTuple`. So the correct cast is:

```
Value = (ValueTuple<ThisThing, bool>)parameter;
```

Or using the tuple syntax:

```
Value = ((ThisThing, bool))parameter;
```

Comment: And if you want the items to be named: Value = ((ThisThing MyThing, bool MyBool))parameter;